# conda not showing updated package

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda, conda

I have tried to install pyhive on a server which is not connected to internet by downloading the file from here (https://anaconda.org/anaconda/pyhive/files?sort=basename&sort_order=asc)

The problem is that the package seems to be installed but when I do `conda list | grep -i hive` I get an old version of the package listed.

Below is my terminal output

```
(base) raemon@someserver:~$ sudo /opt/anaconda/bin/conda install pyhive-0.6.1-py27_0.tar.bz2
WARNING: The conda.compat module is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
(base) raemon@someserver:~$ conda list | grep -i hive
WARNING: The conda.compat module is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(138): Could not remove or rename /opt/anaconda2/conda-meta/thrift-0.9.3-py27h14c3975_1.json.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
libarchive                3.3.3                h5d8350f_5
pyhive                    0.1.7                    pypi_0    pypi
python-libarchive-c       2.8                      py27_6
```

When i try to remove the pyhive by using

```
sudo conda remove --offline pyhive
```

I get this

```
WARNING: The conda.compat module is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
Collecting package metadata: done
Solving environment: /
The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
The following packages are causing the inconsistency:

  - <unknown>/linux-64::psycopg2==2.7.6.1=py27h1ba5d50_0
  - <unknown>/noarch::pyviz==0.10.3=py_0
  - <unknown>/linux-64::plotly==3.1.1=py37h28b3542_0
  - <unknown>/noarch::holoviews==1.12.3=py_2
  - defaults/linux-64::anaconda==2019.03=py27_0
done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /opt/anaconda2

  removed specs:
    - pyhive


The following packages will be REMOVED:

  pyhive-0.6.1-py27_0


Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
```

After that if I do conda list i get that old version.

```
(base) raemon@someserver:~$ conda list | grep -i hive
WARNING: The conda.compat module is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(138): Could not remove or rename /opt/anaconda2/conda-meta/thrift-0.9.3-py27h14c3975_1.json.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
libarchive                3.3.3                h5d8350f_5
pyhive                    0.1.7                    pypi_0    pypi
python-libarchive-c       2.8                      py27_6
```

Why is conda not updating the version when I am installing i.e. pyhive-0.6.1-py27_0.tar.bz2 ?

Comment: try `conda remove pyhive` followed by `pip uninstall pyhive`, then `conda install pyhive`

Comment: @cel pip lists pyhive as version 6.1 which is good, I do not want to touch the pip's pyhive

Comment: in the case you installed the same package with both conda and pip, it usually helps to uninstall the package completely with both conda and pip. This is why I recommended uninstalling also with pip. You can reinstall version 6.1 later.

Comment: No change, even though I uninstalled via pip. It stil lists pyhive 6

Comment: What happens if you uninstall it again with pip? Does pip still find it?

Comment: @cel thankyou, it seemed pip had 2 versions, 6 & 1.7, after i uninstalled 6, it asked if i wanted to remove 1.7(which is interesting, i thought this would be auto-removed) so i uninstalled 1.7 & then installed 6.1 by pip & conda, all is good now